# Why cache data is not deleting on app destroy

Tags: java, android, android-ondestroy

When I try using the code bellow in the `onDestroy()` method in MainActivity it seams it does not work. What I am doing wrong?

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    deleteCacheData();
}

public void deleteCacheData() {
    File cacheDir = this.getCacheDir();
    File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();

    if (files != null) {
        for (File file : files) {
            file.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two cases with your code:

1. You can't reliably depends on the case that `onDestroy()` method will be called. Because there is no such guarantee that it will always be called by  the system. Here the excerpt from [`onDestroy()` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()):

   > protected void onDestroy ()
   >
   > Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it), or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.
   >
   > Note: do not count on this method being called as a place for saving data! For example, if an activity is editing data in a content provider, those edits should be committed in either onPause() or onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), not here. This method is usually implemented to free resources like threads that are associated with an activity, so that a destroyed activity does not leave such things around while the rest of its application is still running. There are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it, so it should not be used to do things that are intended to remain around after the process goes away.
   >
   > Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.
2. You should call your `deleteCacheData()` before calling the `super.onDestroy()`. So, this is incorrect:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       deleteCacheData();
   }
   ```

   this is the correct one:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       deleteCacheData();
       super.onDestroy();
   }
   ```

Comment: In my case onDestroy() is never called (btw thanks for the fix I ve tried still not working).  So, what's the most common practice for cleaning app cache? I mean I can't rely that the OS will do the job before my app starts crashing.

Comment: I don't know how the common practice to handle this case. But I will use a `SharedPreferences` to save a flag marking that a `dirty` cache need to be clear. Then whenever starting the activity, I'll check the flag and do the clean up.

Comment: I set the cleaning in onPause() override method and its a charm. Using SharedPreferences iis also a smart move. Thanks a lot

Comment: It's glad to hear that you've solved the problem, and you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you using Windows OS
Because In your Windows task manaegr one Process is Running when the **android studio** start or build run or stop named

Java Jmt first stop it then your can directly delete the both build folder not need to clear cache

Comment: the app is running on Android OS. What I wanna do is clear the cache on app destroy(exit)

Comment: sorry but my answer for delete cache of android studio

Comment: it's the app cache on an actual phone but thanks for trying :)